# lissajous curves in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Sup guys i need to write code in js to move image in canvas in a lissajous curves.
With small help i managed to write a code which is moving a small point in these curves but really dont know how to replace it with image(any image). 
Here is my code:

```js
function start() {
  var ctx, WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y, dx, dy, angle, timeout;

  function init(data) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    WIDTH = 500;
    HEIGHT = 300;
    x = WIDTH / 2;
    y = HEIGHT / 2;
    dx = x * Math.sin(0);
    dy = x * Math.sin(0);
    angle = 0;
    draw((m1 = 1), (m2 = 2), (speed = 0.009));
  }

  function line(x, y, dx, dy, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(dx, dy);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5; // adding here to make it more visible
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  function draw() {
    timeout = setTimeout(draw, 1);
    clear();
    nx = (x - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m1);
    ny = (y - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m2);
    line(x + dx, y + dy, x + nx, y + ny);
    dx = nx;
    dy = ny;
    angle += speed;
  }
  init();
}
start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Really appreciate any help because im stuck right now. Im totally new into this
and need this for school. Thanks!!!

Comment: you want to replace the point with image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

I'm adding a code sample here, with some part of your code commented so you can see the edits :)

```js
function start() {
  var ctx, WIDTH, HEIGHT, x, y, dx, dy, angle, phaseAngle, timeout;
  var image = document.getElementById("img");

  function init(data) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //WIDTH = 500;
    //HEIGHT = 300;
    WIDTH = canvas.width;
    HEIGHT = canvas.height;
    PI = 3.14159265;
    x = WIDTH / 2;
    y = HEIGHT / 2;
    angle = 0;
    phaseAngle = PI/2;
    //dx = x * Math.sin(0);
    //dy = x * Math.sin(0);
    dx = (x - 50) * Math.sin(angle);
    dy = (y - 50) * Math.sin(angle+phaseAngle);
    //angle = 0;
    draw((m1 = 1), (m2 = 2), (speed = 0.009));
  }

  function line(x, y, dx, dy, r) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
    // ctx.beginPath();
    // ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    // ctx.lineTo(dx, dy);
    // ctx.lineWidth = 5; // adding here to make it more visible
    // ctx.stroke();
  }
  function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  function draw() {
    timeout = setTimeout(draw, 1);
    clear();
    //nx = (x - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m1);
    //ny = (y - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m2);
    nx = (x - 50) * Math.sin(angle * m1);
    ny = (y - 50) * Math.sin(angle * m2 + phaseAngle);
    line(x + dx, y + dy, x + nx, y + ny);
    dx = nx;
    dy = ny;
    angle += speed;
  }
  init();
}
start();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<img id="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRMrk.png" hidden> <!-- hide image, we need it only inside canvas -->
```

**Edit**: Changed the formula for the curve. The added phase angle makes the curve run in a 90 degree angle (a 270 degree angle will produce the same curve).

> Lissajous figure, also called BOWDITCH CURVE, pattern produced by the intersection of two sinusoidal curves the axes of which are at right angles to each other.
>   Refer to: https://www.britannica.com/science/Lissajous-figure

Comment: That’s exactly what i wanted thanks so much! Works Perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [THREE.js](https://threejs.org/%20%22THREEjs%22?)? It's super great for this kind of stuff. I think you will find it much more extensible in the long run.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfx8wyff/2/) I made for what you're talking about. JsFiddle doesn't allow cross-origin requests so I can't actually load an image for you, just replace "path/to/image" with wherever your image url is.

```
function start() {
  var renderer, scene, camera, mesh;
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var m1 = 1;
  var m2 = 2;
  var speed = 0.009;
  var angle = 0;
  var x = width/2;
  var y = height/2;

  function init(data) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set(x, y, 50);

    var g = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(30, 30);
    var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "pink"});
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(g, mat)
    mesh.position.set(x, y, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load("path/to/image", function(img) {
      mat.map = img;
      mat.needsUpdate = true;
    });
  }

  function update() {
    var nx = (x - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m1);
    var ny = (y - 5) * Math.sin(angle * m2);

    mesh.position.set(x + nx, y + ny, 0);
    angle += speed;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

  init();
  update();
}
start();
```

Comment: I guess i would use three.js in my another project thanks for reply i will use that fiddle to Help others in my group